# node and npm are not showing installed using control -v etc

Tags: macos

Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
Target /usr/local/include/node/common.gypi
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
scottiefew@Scotties-MBP ~ % brew link --overwrite node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.12.0... 
Error: Could not symlink include/node/common.gypi
/usr/local/include/node is not writable.
scottiefew@Scotties-MBP ~ %